# Редирект с "?" на конце url на без "?"

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите создать рабочее правило в htaccess для редиректа с "?" на конце url на без "?"

честно скажу в регулярках и правилах я не очень силен)

Comment: Может все же наоборот?
Т.е. `http://mydomain.tk/new/3/` на `http://mydomain.tk/?module=new&page=3`   
Или Вы все таки хотите:
С `http://mydomain.tk/?module=new&page=3` на `http://mydomain.tk/new/3/` ?

Comment: нет именно так, причем там есть урлы как http://mydomain.tk/?module=new&page=3 такого вида та ки нормальные
 и при некоторых условиях у нормальных остаются хвосты
http://mydomain.tk/module? например так
 и вот от таких хвостов и нужно избавиться не разрушаю  передачу гет параметров

Comment: Вы хотите что бы в строке браузера был короткий url, а системе читала его как длиную штуку с GET параметрами, так?

Comment: нет, не надо усложнять, просто если на конце урла стоит один лишь "?"
 убираем его редиректом на тот же урл без "?"

если там гет параметр то бог  с ним ничего не делаем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем не найдя адекватного и простого решения через директивы htaccsess я сделал это на PHP дешево и сердито)

```
    $rest = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -1);
    if($rest=='?'){
         $url= substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -1);
         header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
            strtolower($url), true, 301);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1? [R,L]
```

Comment: к несчастью нет, эта правило убивает все чпу вытаскивая внутриние  пути роутизации